# running a task on UI every x seconds

Tags: multithreading, android

I often come around a requirement where we have to perform a repetitive task on the user's screen (for eg, updating a counter like flash sale/ live class timer, autoscrolling the banner, etc) .
I have written this small file which performs a basic task of pressing a button every 2 seconds for a total of 4 times as a general example and my approach to this problem
Please review and provide your inputs about weather this would be a correct approach or not.

```kotlin
class AVCActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var scrollInterval = 0
    private var run4Times = false
    private val handler = Handler()
    private var count = 0
   

    override fun onCreate(b:Bundle) {
        scrollInterval = 2000
        run4Times = api.runRepetitiveTask() 
        // task will start in onResume
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        handler.clearStack()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(run4Times){
            handler.clearStack().postDelayed(scrollTask,scrollInterval.toLong())
        }
    }

    private fun Handler.clearStack():Handler{
        this.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        return this
    }

    private val scrollTask = object : Runnable{
        override fun run() {
            if(count < 4){
                count + =1
                btHello?.performOnClick()
                handler.clearStack().postDelayed(this,scrollInterval.toLong())
            }
            else{
                run4Times = false
                handler.clearStack()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some details:

1. handler fires the runnable **every 2 seconds via recursion  for 3 times** . on the 4th time, the **runnable clears the handler and closes handler recursion**
2. **handler gets started in onResume and stopped in onPause** to handle case where user has closed the screen before completion of the original task. **The condition to weather make the handler fire the runnable is handled via a global variable, initialised in onCreate()** .i,e only once .
3. **handler is NOT started in onCreate**  because this will cause the handler to run same runnable twice(since onCreate->onResume) . this usually causes a bug where we assume the runnable to run once every 2 seconds, but ends up with 2 runnables running every 2 seconds
4. **every postCall is made after handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)** (via extension function `clearStack()` ) , thereby removing any unprocessed runnables. this is especially required in a case of onResume() , **since onResume can be called multiple times** and this could lead to same problem as point 3. using this function prevents this case from occurring.
5. **variables like handler and runnable are global** to prevent duplication/re assigning.
6. i**t is safe to access ui views** in runnable  because the handler is going to run the runnable in main thread (my assumption)

---

Anything else should i be considering? Is it a good general approach? any memory leaks in this approach?

PS :  I think this question might have been asked before, but i am not sure if this has been asked in context to Android/kotlin. Kindly point me to an already asked question with better approach if this is repetitive